# Error installing Ruby on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

The following install commands:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys         409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3


 \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

Returns this error:

```
 Installing requirements for ubuntu.
 Updating system................
 Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.2.1',
showing last 15 lines of /home/gav/.rvm/log/1458060663_ruby-                                      2.2.1/update_system.log     ++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  78 > case  "${TERM:-   dumb}" in   ++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  81 > case "$1" in
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  83 > [[ -t 2 ]]
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  83 > return 1
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_error()  117 > printf %b 'There has       been error while updating '\''apt-get'\'', please give it some time and   try again later.
404 errors should be fixed for rvm to proceed. Check your sources   configured in:
 /etc/apt/sources.list
 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
\n'
There has been error while updating 'apt-get', please give it some  time     and try again later.
404 errors should be fixed for rvm to proceed. Check your sources    configured in:
/etc/apt/sources.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list

++ /scripts/functions/requirements/ubuntu :    requirements_debian_update_system()  53 > return 100
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review your question, especially its formatting. It's really important to format a question so it can be quickly and easily read by those trying to help you. Not doing that is interpreted as lack of effort and not wanting help bad enough to help us. "[ask]"

Comment: The error appears to be a networking or hosting problem. RVM can't update  your `apt-get` due to 404 errors. This isn't a Ruby or Rails problem.

Comment: How do I solve this.  I don't have network issue, it mentions Check your sources    configured in:
/etc/apt/sources.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problems with your sources

heres one solution, open a terminal type in

```
sudo apt-get update
```

take note of the names that are causing the 404s, errors, etc.

then open your software center and choose sources
[image]

there pick "Other Software" (second tab)
[image]

expand that window and start disabling the repositories that cause you trouble
[image]

as you uncheck any repositories, try again

```
sudo apt-get update
```

until you see no errors
[image]

make sure you don't see any errors or not found sources

afterward type in

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

and

```
rvm requirements
```

[image]

and That's it...